# PHP and CKEditor included image does not show in the email

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I have the following page to send newsletters.

[page](http://raveen.comlu.com/5000.php)

When I include an image from the toolbar icon. It displays correctly realtime. But however when I click Send, email gets the message without the image. Just only the message (formatted text by the editor shows correctly)

My image is located in this URL: http://raveen.comlu.com/sport.jpg

Also I print content made by the editor after sending message as well;
Even there also, image does not show on the page(see screenshot)

[image: screenshot]

I have the following code;

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title> A simple page with CKEditor </title>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <!-- Create a <textarea> element first -->
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>

        <script>
            //replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor instance
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

            //Retrieve data from CKEditor instance with ID of editor1
            var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData()

        </script>

        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Send">
    </form>

    <?php
        if( isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) ){

            $editor_data = $_POST['editor1'];
            echo $editor_data;


            $to = "receiver1@yahoo.com, receiver2@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Here is the subject";

            $message = $editor_data;

            $header = "From: Sender Name <senderemail@gmail.com> \r\n";

            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
            $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8 \r\n";

            $retval = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $header );

            if( $retval == true ){
                echo "Message sent successfully";
            }
            else{
                echo "Message could not be sent!";
            }
        }
    ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your quotes from your editor data are being escaped so you can try adding this line before `echo $editor_data;`

```
$editor_data = stripslashes($editor_data);
```